# Azure ARM: Remove-AzureRmKeyVault -Force not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

In Azure RM Powershell the statement

```
Remove-AzureRmKeyVault -InputObject $sdvobjKeyVault -Force
```

always pops up with the prompt whether I really want to execute that action - '*-Force*' seems to get ignored! Now then, how to have a KV deleted from a RG **without user interaction** via Azure Powershell?

Comment: try updating you azure powershell to latest and start using Az instead of AzureRm module (`Install-Module Az`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the same behavior here.  Adding -Force suppresses the confirmation as expected.

Any reason you are using the old AzureRm commands?  You should start making the move to the Az commands.  Here is a good reference for KeyVaults including the ability to manage the Soft Delete for vaults.

MS Docs Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-soft-delete-powershell

Comment: Hmm, just had the issue now; I checked again and yes, `Remove-AzureRmKeyVault -InputObject $sdvobjKeyVault -Force` is executed with a popup in the middle of deployment, maybe its a bug in my version. But thanks for the link, I will give a a read now. What else could I do except for leaving that KV alive to avoid the popup question?

Comment: Which version are you running and how are you running the commands?

Comment: Script     6.7.3      AzureRM.Resources 
I am running the code from a ps1 script on my local machine. I am setting up a KV (to create a certificate) but then like to delete the KV once the script has run.